# Haskell Massiv Array Size Limit

Tags: haskell, massiv

If Massiv, as well as other array libraries use Int for indexing, then how does one construct and index arrays larger than 2^29 elements? Int can only be as large as 2^29. I noticed in the source code that Linear indexing is used on array operations aswell so I would assume that just writing a vector as a two dimensional array would still have the same issue.

Is there a solution to this within Massiv or is there another array library suitable for arrays with more than 2^29 elements?

Edit: @Thomas just mentioned that the maxBound of Int is machine dependent. How ever I would still like to know how to index arrays with a number of elements greater than the maxBound of Int.

Comment: An `Int` is _at least_ as large as 2^29; it might be larger on your implementation, and is probably closer to 64 bits on a modern system (use `maxBound` to check).

Comment: I presume the size of `Int` is also always approximately the size of the largest block of memory you can address. So it is probably simply impossible to create larger arrays.

Comment: With over 3.5 exabytes (64bit Int, single bit indexing) required I doubt you got the memory anyways.

Comment: Why do you need such array? If you have some sort of permutation, often a `Map` is used to map the "special" cases for example. This is often very small compared to the number of "regular" items.

Comment: If you have to allocate such an array, probably you are using the wrong data structure

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem when I originally asked the question, I thought the limit was 2^29. Which is small enough to cause a problem in applications involving loading large files for scientific computing. But for 2^64, that isn’t a practical concern I was just curious if it was possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to create a list that contains more than `maxBound :: Int` elements in memory, because the size of an `Int` is generally expected to be sufficient to cover the full addressable memory space. A hypothetical list or array of length greater than `maxBound :: Int` on your system therefore would not fit in addressable memory and could not be stored, thus there is no need for a mechanism by which one could index into such a structure.